# Update amount of particles

Tags: three.js, particles

Please see attached fiddle. I would like to update the amount of particles with a click event.

So far I have only been able to update the camera settings.

Have gone through the three.js docs on updating things, but would appreciate a push in the right direction.

I was trying something along the lines of:

```
document.onclick = myClickHandler;

function myClickHandler() {           
    particle = new THREE.Sprite( material );
    particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    particle.position.normalize();
    particle.position.multiplyScalar( Math.random() * 10 + 150 );
   particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 10;
   scene.add( particle );
    geometry.vertices.push( particle.position );
    }
```

Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/007zmukr/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.
Basically by...
Making the geometry and material variables global.
Separating the particle generation into a separate function, `addParticle`.
calling `addParticle` within the initial particle generation loop and from within the click handler.

Pretty much what you did above except moving it into it's own function.

https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/007zmukr/26/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for!